# Some procedures do not have the blue dots in Delphi XE7 when the project is builded

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am using Delphi XE7.

When I build (Shift + F9) my project (Win 32 platform) the blue dots do not appear in the source code of some procedures. Because of that it is impossible to trace the instructions of these procedures.

My project has 33 forms, 1 data module form with 18 queries (TFDQuery), one for each table of the database. The biggest unit is the unit of the data module form (25,866 lines).

1. Project Manager Build Configuration = Debug.
2. Project Option:

   1. Delphi Compiler > Compiling:
      Debug information = Debug information;
      Local symbols = true;
      Symbol reference info = reference info.
   2. Delphi Compiler > Linking:
      Assertions = true;
      Include remote debugging = true;
      Map file = Detailed.

Comment: Is this code inside conditionals? Is it used anywhere? Do you have any compiler hints about unused procedures?

Comment: Works fine here. How can we reproduce.

Comment: Common cause for some functions not being debuggable include them having been stripped because never called, or them being inline. As I seem to have said a million times though, if you don't demonstrate thee problem, how can we solve if definitively?

Comment: Thank you Jerry!
After two days trying to solve this problem finally somebody gave me a big clue: "unused procedures".
I have noticed that the procedures without the blue dots are not used. 
The blue dots only appear in the source code of the used procedures after the project is built (Shift+F9).

Comment: The linker strips functions that it can prove are not called